# Starting a tikz loop at the margin. How do I properly specify the starting position?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, margins, memoir, unit-of-measure

I am attempting to encourage the reader to take notes in my book by making extra-wide margins and drawing lines down the outer edge. But I can't seem to get the lines to start in the right place.

**Expectation**: For even pages, the first line should be x-offset by the left margin and y-offset by the top margin + the header. If I start the line under the headsep and draw them as wide as the marginpar, they should fit neatly into the page margins every time

**Reality**: I suspect there is a mismatch between the units I am offsetting by and the units I am expecting. So the horizontal offset is much larger than expected and the vertical offset is much smaller than expected. I'm not sure how to account for that without setting it to an absolute position, but I'm clearly misunderstanding something

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc,fancyhdr}
 
% define the margins and text block size
\setlrmarginsandblock{14mm}{50mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{27mm}{22mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% define the image command. This command should draw lines as wide
% as the margin paragraph starting at the top-left corner of the 
% margin and moving down by 15pt until it runs out of text block. 
% The first line is red just to illustrate where the pattern starts
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\drawNoteRules}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lineSpacing}{15 pt}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yPosOffset}{\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep}
    \foreach \y in {0,\lineSpacing,...,\textheight} {
        \ifnum\y=0
            \draw[red] (current page.north west) ++(\leftmargin,-\y-\yPosOffset mm) -- ++(\marginparwidth,0);
        \else   
            \draw[] (current page.north west) ++(\leftmargin,-\y-\yPosOffset mm) -- ++(\marginparwidth,0);
        \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% fancy header that pushes into the margins, add the tikz image to the header
\fancypagestyle{bookpage}{
    \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
    \fancyhead[EL]{\thepage\drawNoteRules}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{bookpage}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: actual image. not offset by expected amount]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are interested in getting a drawing showing layout parameters of pages of your document, via  `\usepackage{layout}` load the package [layout](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/layout.pdf) and use the command `\layout`.

---

From vertical margins you only specify the top-margin, the head-height and the head-sep. The bottom-margin comes into being by placing a textblock of height `\textheight` whose top border is on vertical position `1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep` and whose height is `\textheight` on a paper of height `\paperheight`. `\topskip` is the distance between the baseline of the first line of the textblock and the top border of the textblock.

Thus from the top border of the page to the baseline of the first line of the textblock you have a vertical distance of `1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip`.

With your TikZ-pictures you calculate from `(current page.north west)`, which is in the top left corner of the page, thus everything needs to go downward=needs to go upward in *negative* direction.

With pages of twoside-documents:

- LaTeX considers pages with

  - even page numbers to be left hand pages/verso-pages.
  - odd page numbers to be right hand pages/recto-pages.
- From the horizontal margins you only specify the left margin. The right margin comes into being as the result of there being a left margin and a textblock of width `\textwidth` on a paper of width `\paperwidth`.
- From horizontal margins you specify left margins for the case of there being a verso page/left hand page and for the case of there being a recto page/right hand page.
- From the left border of the paper of pages that have odd page numbers (right hand pages/recto pages) to the left border of the textblock you have a horizontal distance of `1in + \oddsidemargin`. (That's the inner margins with a double page of a book with a verso page on the left and a recto page on the right.)
- From the left border of the paper of pages that have even page numbers (left hand pages/verso pages) to the left border of the textblock you have a horizontal distance of `1in + \evensidemargin`. (That's the outer margins with a double page of a book with a verso page on the left and a recto page on the right.)
- With a right hand page/recto page/a page whose page number is odd, from the right border of the textblock to the left border of a margin-paragraph in the right margin you have a gap of with `\marginparsep`. Margin-paragraphs are of width `\marginparwidth`.
- With a left hand page/verso page/a page whose page number is even, from the left border of the textblock to the right border of a margin-paragraphs in the left margin you have a gap of with `\marginparsep`. Margin-paragraphs are of width `\marginparwidth`.
- If you use `\reversemarginpar`, then with twoside-documents margin-paragraphs will be on the inner margins and with one-side-documents margin-paragraphs will be on the right margin instead of the left margin.
- It is said that ratio outer horizontal margin:inner horizontal margin usually is to be 2:1 so that the vertical stripe formed by the two inner horizontal margins is of same width as each of the vertical stripes that form the outer horizontal margins. I (Ulrich Diez, the author of the first version of this answer, October 16, 2023) prefer ratio top:outer:inner:bottom = 4:6:3:8 while calculating `\textheight` so that `\textheight`-`\topskip` is a multiple of `\baselineskip`. But all this is a matter of taste, so your settings were not changed in the example below. But with the example below the freedom was taken to change the line style to dotted. You can easily undo that in your real-life-scenario if you don't like that. ;-)

With pages of "oneside"-documents:

- Recto means the front side of the paper and verso means the back side of the paper.
- Margins for all pages are set according to those parameters that with twoside-documents determine margins of right hand pages/recto pages/pages whose page-numbers are odd.

In any case

- the equation
  `1in` + `\evensidemargin` + `\textwidth` + `1in` + `\oddsidemargin` = `\paperwidth`
  should hold.
- `\marginparwidth` + `\marginparsep` should not exceed `1in` + `\evensidemargin` as otherwise margin-paragraphs stick out of the paper. In case of doing `\reversemarginpar` for having margin-paragraphs on inner margins, `\marginparwidth` + `\marginparsep` should not exceed `1in` + `\oddsidemargin`.
- If `\marginparwidth` + `2`*`\marginparsep`= `1in` + `\evensidemargin`, then the horizontal gap between the outer horizontal paper border and the border of the box containing the margin paragraph is as wide as the horizontal gap between the border of the box containing the textblock and the border of the box containing the margin paragraph.

---

Thickness of lines with TikZ is:

/tikz/ultra thin   -   Sets the line width to 0.1pt = 0.03514598 mm.
/tikz/very thin    -   Sets the line width to 0.2pt = 0.07029196 mm.
/tikz/thin         -   Sets the line width to 0.4pt = 0.14058392 mm.
/tikz/semithick    -   Sets the line width to 0.6pt = 0.21087588 mm.
/tikz/thick        -   Sets the line width to 0.8pt = 0.28116784 mm.
/tikz/very thick   -   Sets the line width to 1.2pt = 0.42175176 mm.
/tikz/ultra thick  -   Sets the line width to 1.6pt = 0.56233568 mm.

---

If you use dimension-registers or `\dimexpr...\relax`, then `\the⟨dimension register⟩` / `\the\dimexpr...\relax` gets you a string of explicit character tokens which denote the length in question converted to the unit `pt`. Trailing character tokens `pt` denoting the unit are a component of the result of `\the`. `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` truncates so that only the integer component of the numerical value of the result of `the` remains. The character tokens denoting the decimal component and the character tokens denoting the unit `pt` are removed by `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`.

When you use a dimension-register or a `\dimexpr...\relax` in place of a count register, without `\the`, then it is treated as an integer which denotes the numerical value of the length in question when it is measured in the unit `sp`.

---

The following might be a starting-point. (But probably a mechanism would be interesting, where for each paragraph y-coordinate of the first baseline and y-coordinate of the last baseline is stored via coordinates in a `[remember picture, overlay]` tikz-picture so that throughout the entire page horizontal lines can be produced that are aligned with the baselines of lines of paragraphs.)

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc,fancyhdr}
 
% define the margins and text block size
\setlrmarginsandblock{14mm}{50mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{27mm}{22mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% define the image command. This command should draw lines as wide
% as the margin paragraph starting at the top-left corner of the 
% margin and moving down by 15pt until it runs out of text block. 
% The first line is red just to illustrate where the pattern starts
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\drawNoteRules}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lineSpacing}{\the\dimexpr15pt\relax}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yPosOffset}{-\the\dimexpr1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip+.4pt\relax}
    \foreach \y in {0,\lineSpacing,...,\textheight} {
        \ifnum\y=0 \draw[red, dotted]\else\draw[dotted]\fi
         (current page.north west) 
         ++(\the\dimexpr\if E#1-\marginparwidth+\else\paperwidth-\fi\dimexpr+1in+\evensidemargin-\marginparsep\relax\relax, \yPosOffset pt-\y pt)%
         -- %
         ++(\the\dimexpr\marginparwidth\relax, 0);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% fancy header that pushes into the margins, add the tikz image to the header
\fancypagestyle{bookpage}{
    \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\drawNoteRules{E}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage\drawNoteRules{O}}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{bookpage}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To the questions you asked in comments:

> There's two things I don't get. For one, what's up with the additions to the y-offset? I get that `\topskip` makes it look better aligned with the text, but where did `+1in` and `+.4pt` come from?

The top margin is  `1in + \topmargin` in LaTeX. When going down `1in + \topmargin` from the top border of the sheet of paper, you reach the top border of the box containing page header. When going down `\headheight` from the top border of the box containing the page header you reach the bottom border of the box containing the page header. When going down `\headsep` from the bottom border of the box containing the page header you reach the top border of the box containing the textblock. When going down `\topskip` from the top border of the box containing the textblock, you reach the baseline of the first line of text of the textblock.
If you draw a horizontal rule on that baseline, that rule can be considered a rectangular bar whose bottom border is aligned with the baseline and whose top border is a bit above the baseline. "A bit above" means ".4pt above" because this is the rule-thickness with this kind of horizontal TikZ-rule. Therefore that horizontal rule needs to be shifted downwards .4pt so that the top border of the rectangular bar which forms the rule is aligned with the baseline of the first line of the textblock.

> And for two, I genuinely do not understand what is happening on line 22.

Line 22 is:

```
++(\the\dimexpr\if E#1-\marginparwidth+\else\paperwidth-\fi\dimexpr+1in+\evensidemargin-\marginparsep\relax\relax, \yPosOffset pt-\y pt)%
```

This line is about coordinates.

The vertical coordinate/y-coordinate is formed by the expression

```
\yPosOffset pt-\y pt
```

.

The horizontal coordinate/x-coordinate is formed by the expression

```
\the\dimexpr\if E#1-\marginparwidth+\else\paperwidth-\fi\dimexpr+1in+\evensidemargin-\marginparsep\relax\relax
```

.

If the argument of `\drawNoteRules` is `E`, then for the horizontal coordinate you get s.th. like:

```
\the\dimexpr
      -\marginparwidth
      +\dimexpr+1in+\evensidemargin-\marginparsep\relax
    \relax
```

`1in + \evensidemargin` is the outer horizontal margin of a sheet of paper of the twoside-document. With even-numbered pages/lefthand-pages/verso-pages the outer horizontal margin of the sheet of paper is the left margin.

So for even-numbered pages/lefthand-pages/verso-pages you specify argument `E` and thus with even-numbered pages/lefthand-pages/verso-pages from the left border of the sheet of paper you go `1in+\evensidemargin` to the right and reach the left border of the box containing the textblock. From the left border of the box containing the textblock you go `\marginparsep` to the left and reach the right border of the box that makes a margin-paragraph. From the right border of the margin-paragraph-box you go `\marginparwidth` to the left and reach the left border of the margin-paragraph-box.  That's the horizontal position of where TiKZ shall begin to draw the horizontal rule. Due to `++(\the\dimexpr\marginparwidth\relax, 0);` from that position the horizontal rule goes to the right and has a length of `\marginparwidth`. Thus the left end of the (dotted) horizontal TiKZ-rule is aligned with the left border of the margin-paragraph-box and the right end of the (dotted) horizontal TiKZ-rule is aligned with the right border of the margin-paragraph-box.

If the argument of `\drawNoteRules` is not `E`, then for the horizontal coordinate you get s.th. like:

```
\the\dimexpr
      \paperwidth
      -\dimexpr+1in+\evensidemargin-\marginparsep\relax
    \relax
```

`1in + \evensidemargin` is the outer horizontal margin of a sheet of paper of the twoside-document. With odd-numbered pages/righthand-pages/recto-pages the outer horizontal margin of the sheet of paper is the right margin.

So for odd-numbered pages/righthand-pages/recto-pages you specify argument other than `E`, e.g., `O`, and thus with odd numbered pages/righthand-pages/recto-pages from the left border of the sheet of paper you go `\paperwidth`  to the right and reach the right border of the sheet of paper. From the right border of the sheet of paper you go `1in+\evensidemargin` to the left and reach the right border of the box containing the textblock. From the right border of the box containing the textblock you go `\marginparsep` to the right and reach the left border of the box that makes a margin-paragraph.  That's the horizontal position of where TiKZ shall begin to draw the horizontal rule. Due to `++(\the\dimexpr\marginparwidth\relax, 0);` from that position the horizontal rule goes to the right and has a length of `\marginparwidth`. Thus the left end of the (dotted) horizontal TiKZ-rule is aligned with the left border of the `\marginpar`-textblock and the right end of the (dotted) horizontal TiKZ-rule is aligned with the right border of the `\marginpar`-textblock.
(Alternatively from the left border of the sheet of paper you could go `1in+\oddsidemargun+\textwidth+\marginparsep` to the right in order to find the left end of the (dotted)  horizontal TiKZ-rule.)

Comment: Okay this is a lot to digest, but I am chewing on it. Most of it makes sense. I'm going to compare this to what I already have and see if I can work out why this works and mine does not.

Comment: Okay, first off this is very nice. I think I like the dotted lines better actually. I like how the command accepts arguments for even or odd pages. There's two things I don't get. For one, what's up with the additions to the y-offset? I get that \topskip makes it look better aligned with the text, but where did +1in and +.4pt come from?
And for two, I genuinely do not understand what is happening on line 22. I tried to plug that expression back into my original document, but now the lines start off the left side of the page. I'll absolutely use this, but I would like to understand it more.

Comment: I'll update the question with my second attempt. I see you are adding and subtracting parameters and I tried to pull out only the ones applicable to the left-hand page, but I guess I failed.

Comment: Actually never mind. I managed to get it to work by doing it the right way, but it's not any clearer.
I clipped this line out and reduced it to ONLY the even page expression. What is it actually doing? Why are we subtracting \marginparsep twice and adding one inch and subtracting marginparwidth? Is all of that really necessary? Why doesn't it work to just shift the x origin to the right by \evensidemargin?

Comment: \draw[] (current page.north west) ++(\the\dimexpr-\marginparwidth+1in+\evensidemargin-\marginparsep\relax, \yPosOffset pt-\y pt) -- ++(\the\dimexpr\marginparwidth\relax,0);

Comment: @anthony I just added some remarks to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's an extremely informative and helpful answer. I think I understand a bit better now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you a direction:

[image: result]

What I changed is introducing some arbitrary shift into y-direction downwards of the coordinate of `current page.north west`, and added a few more lipsum paragraphs to have a 4th page:

```
    \foreach \y in {0,\lineSpacing,...,\textheight} {
        \ifnum\y=0
            \draw[red] ([yshift=-2cm] current page.north west) ++(\leftmargin,-\y-\yPosOffset mm) -- ++(\marginparwidth,0);
        \else   
            \draw[] ([yshift=-2cm] current page.north west) ++(\leftmargin,-\y-\yPosOffset mm) -- ++(\marginparwidth,0);
        \fi
    }
```

This isn't yet perfect, as the starting position is certainly determined by layout parameters, i.e. different than the `2cm` I just set. For reference your whole, almost unchanged, code, as described above:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc,fancyhdr}
 
% define the margins and text block size
\setlrmarginsandblock{14mm}{50mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{27mm}{22mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% define the image command. This command should draw lines as wide
% as the margin paragraph starting at the top-left corner of the 
% margin and moving down by 15pt until it runs out of text block. 
% The first line is red just to illustrate where the pattern starts
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\drawNoteRules}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lineSpacing}{15 pt}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yPosOffset}{\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep}
    \foreach \y in {0,\lineSpacing,...,\textheight} {
        \ifnum\y=0
            \draw[red] ([yshift=-2cm] current page.north west) ++(\leftmargin,-\y-\yPosOffset mm) -- ++(\marginparwidth,0);
        \else   
            \draw[] ([yshift=-2cm] current page.north west) ++(\leftmargin,-\y-\yPosOffset mm) -- ++(\marginparwidth,0);
        \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% fancy header that pushes into the margins, add the tikz image to the header
\fancypagestyle{bookpage}{
    \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
    \fancyhead[EL]{\thepage\drawNoteRules}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{bookpage}
\lipsum[1-28]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is definitely a solution, but I don't know that it gets at the crux of the issue. I could just as easily add `[yshift=-2.75cm, xshift=-0.665cm]` to the draw command and it looks perfect, but I'm looking to use the existing page/margin parameters to do that instead of setting it manually. I'm pretty sure I've messed up in the application of the \yPosOffset and \leftmargin properties, but I'm not sure how I would fix it.

Comment: Thank you. // I suggest to wait a little. Here are many seasoned users who know these parameters by heart. I'm sure, they'll answer soon.

Comment: I do appreciate the input. If all else fails I will go with this and you did bring up a method of ofsetting the origin that I didn't know about.